# Can I use Entity Framework from C++/CLI project

Tags: entity-framework, c++-cli

Is there any way to actually use Entity Framework from C++/CLI project? Or does it have to be .Net project in order to use Entity Framework?

Comment: @SomeDebilWhoDownvoted - Any reason for downvoting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use from c++/Cli, it is not limited to .net

Comment: could you please provide more info about it, that is explain how to access database created via Entity Framework from C++/CLI. In the C++/CLI project I have, I've tried to install EntityFramework and alas I am getting installation error. I was looking into that issue and you can't simply install entity framework in C++/CLI project.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando "I am getting installation error" What error are you getting?

Comment: @DavidYaw Hi, thanks for asking. After trying to install EntityFramework from Package Manager from inside Visual Studio 2015 I'm getting this error: 
Error  'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCProjectShim' in Assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable. I would be really grateful if you could help me with it. Thanks

Comment: Entity Framework is a managed framework for managed projects c# and vb.NET so you can't install and using it inside vc++ native project.